# how to access / pass the request map in a moustache handler

Tags: clojure, ring

I want to create a handler function which takes two inputs. One is a parameter taken from the url `/name`, and second is a param from the query string `/name?x=3`

```
(def my-app (app
               [page-name] (handler page-name)))

(defn handler
  [{:keys [params]} page-name]
  (let [x (params "x")]
    (-> (page-templ page-name x) response constantly)))
```

The above fails because the handler is expecting 2 params, however I am only passing one.

How do I get hold of the request map, and pass it to the handler ?

The request map in the above case contains a param named `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best if you could dispatch on the page name, like that:

```
(app
 [""] (index-page)
 ["login"] (serve-login))
```

Here functions index-page and serve-login return function of one argument.

```
(defn index-page[]
  (fn [req] ..))
```

req is the request that will contain all the url parameters in key/value map. To get parameter value do this:

```
(-> req (get :params) (get :x))
```

So the full solution would look something like this:

```
(def my-app (app
               ["page1-name"] (handler)))

(defn handler []
  (fn [req]
    (let [x (-> req :params :x)]
      (-> (page-templ page-name x) response))))
```

**EDIT:** Don't forget to wrap you application into (wrap-keyword-params) and (wrap-params), here's how you can do it:

```
(def my-wrapped-app
  (-> my-app
   (wrap-keyword-params)
   (wrap-params))
```

Comment: Another thing, you shouldn't use constantly if response depends on request. **constantly** is used to quickly return response that is request agnostic, meaning it does not care whether you have any parameters or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was immensely helpful. Now I am defining all my functions in the above manner. However I am not able to get the wrap-keyword-params work. I still get string keys. I have posted my code to https://github.com/murtaza52/hs-ex

Comment: Sorry can't get your web-app running, but I think that if you specify wrappers within app macro you need to reverse their order: (app (wrap-params) (wrap-keyword-params) [""] (serve-index))

Comment: Yes that will be the mistake. Let me correct it. Also how did you try running it? Also I have two routes [""] and ["/"], both pointing to the same handler (serve-index), is there a way to specify one route for both instead of two separate ones ?

Comment: You don't need to have routing for "/", dispatch only on "". For deeper levels use something like ["level1" "level2"] this corresponds to URL host/level1/level2. Answering your first question, I cloned your repository and executed lein repl, I saw that you have hook in project.clj, it couldn't load templates.

Comment: I have a resources dir in my public which I have symlinked in my src dir, so that enlive can pick it up from src. Which OS do u have, maybe its not creating the symlink ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16583/discussion-between-murtaza52-and-ivan)